# Can I think of correlation coefficient in terms of conditional probability?

Tags: probability, correlation, classification

My first entry here, sorry if I'm in the wrong place. I'm doing classification of speakers based on short speech samples. "Short" means ~2000-dimensional vectors. To make a Bayesian classifier I'd need to finding a density function in this space, and all attempts with Parzen windows, nearest-neighbor densities etc have failed. I'd like to map vectors down to the real line using correlation, but is there any way to interpret Pearson correlation as the density of one vector conditional on the other? The "other" in this case would be the stored sample--the training sample--so I consider it a parameter, or model. But I still can't figure out how I might define a conditional density.

Comment: If you have a multinormal distribution, then conditional expectation can be calculated via correlation.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you tell me how I might go about doing that?

Comment: Did you look at the wikipedia entry:  https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Multivariate_normal_distribution&redirect=no

Comment: Didn't even occur to me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Kjetil, thank you, that was very helpful. -Dave